# Can't use localStorage in Quip?

Tags: quip

I'm making a customize live app on Quip. In that customization, I need to save the state so that the value stays after refreshing the page. I tried using `localStorage` but it gave me the `Reference Error`. Is there a way I can hold the value?

Comment: One way I can think of the workaround for this is to create a document called like, storage, and put/update info(data) every time to use it as a temporary database?

Answer (score 0):

Quip has its own storage component, which states on the [document](https://mitsubishicorporationamericas.quip.com/dev/liveapps/documentation#record)